# Trouble including jquery in page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I'm working my way through http://www.packtpub.com/article/data-tables-datatables-plugin-jquery-1.3-with-php, to try to utilize the datatables jquery plugin.

```
  <base href="http://localhost/projectname/">

  <script src='//dgdsbygo8mp3h.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/blank.gif' data-original="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src='//dgdsbygo8mp3h.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/blank.gif' data-original="js/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
</script> 
<style type="text/css">
  @import "js/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css";</style> 
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#the_table').dataTable(); 
  }); 
</script>
```

When I run this and check chrome developer tools console I see:

```
GET http://localhost/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css 404 (Not Found) myview:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined masterlist:12
GET http://localhost/myproject/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css 404 (Not Found)
```

I want to include jquery ( which I have locally in myproject/js/jquery.js ) in the project, byt this does not seem to be working. I thought:

```
 <script src='//dgdsbygo8mp3h.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/blank.gif' data-original="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

would do it. Can someone explain why this is not working

Addendum: Following Orangepill's directions my code is now:

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <base href="<?=base_url();?>">

  <script src='js/jquery.js'></script> # LINE 8

<script src='js/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>
<style type="text/css">
  @import "js/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css";</style> 
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#the_table').dataTable(); 
  });
```

The only remaining error in dev tools is:

GET http/localhost/myproject/my_controller/js/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css 404 (Not Found) on line 8

I'm not sure why my_controller is in there. If this was out ( i.e.

```
http/localhost/myproject/js/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css )
```

I think it would work.

Comment: So is anything loading? Looks like your css aren't loading either; why would your jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src='//dgdsbygo8mp3h.cloudfront.net/sites/default/files/blank.gif' data-original="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
```

I believe the data-original notation was a copy paste error from somewhere that had some lazy loading processing happening.

for the issue with your css try to change from a import to a head link

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='js/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css'/>
```

it appears as though import is not respecting your base tag

Comment: view source and see what the base href is being set to... it's almost like it's nixing the `://` from there and trying to load it from a path relative to that

Comment: <base href="http://localhost/myproject/"> -- which is what I thought it should be

Comment: You were right again : <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css'/> worked. Thank you!